# Run a code without any users online - Twitch API

Tags: php, database, api, twitch

Okay this might sound stupid? But is it possible to make my website / server run a code without the need of a user to trigger the code?

I need this for a website linked to a twitch streamer. Unfortunately (by my knowledge) the twitch api only allows you to retrieve information about a channel when it's online.

This makes it impossible for me to display a follower / sub counter unless the streamer is online.

I know i could store the last registerede amount in my database, but the site could potentialy be without any viewers while the streamer is online for quite a while and therefore not be really precise.

It is not a requirement that no users are online, i want the code to run also when nobody is online :)

so to sum it up:
Is it possible to run a code without users online?

Else if anybody knows an alternative than the regular twitch api Kraken that could fix this it would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can schedule jobs to run using cron / windows task scheduler but there is no guarantee that there are no users online. you'd have to check that in your script.

Comment: Okay i will try to search it up :) And i will fix my question, it is not required that no users are online, i just want the code to also run without users online :) My mistake.

Comment: You can use CronJob from your cPanel if you use a Linux servers. By writing the code your script will run after equal intervals as you set in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a proggrammer you will need to run many scripts automaticly, and the best way to do that is by making a crontab.
If you are using a linux you can check [this](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)
and if you are a windows user you can check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/)

Comment: Thanks, i read about it and it seems to work like a charm! :)

Comment: Iam happy to hear that. Olso dont forget to add at the very top of your script the file declaration type #!/usr/bin/env php

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but could you clarify? :)

Comment: If you wand to execute a php script from terminal you do it in this way php script.php but when executing from crontab the server maybe will dont know what the type of the file is thats why u have to declare jt